# Location of MAP sensor in Ford Mondeo 2.2 TDCI (MK3, 2006)?

Tags: ford, turbocharger, power-loss, mondeo

My car has a pending fault P0235 (Turbo Charger Boost Sensor "A" Circuit), the turbo charger does not work and there's a huge lack of power. The turbo itself is most probably (mechanically) ok and I also checked the turbo control unit, all wire straps are intact and clean.

Now I read that the error may come from the MAP sensor. I wanted to dismantle the sensor to clean it or replace it with a new one, but I can't find it anywhere. There's so little space and I have no clue where I should start looking, I also did not find anything after hours of googling.

Can someone describe where this thing sits? Or even better, can someone give me an annotated photo of the engine bay so that I can see where I have to start digging? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Duratorq engine, which is also used in the Jaguar, then the location of that sensor is in the pipe on the lhs front of the engine coming up from underneath and connecting to the EGR valve which is top left hand front corner of the engine. The left hand side is standing at the front of the car looking at the engine - the right hand side has the battery that side.

Update : you should check the turbo control mechanism for cycling, when the ignition is switched on - don't have to start, but the mechanism should operate : the common issues are seizing or the control actuator connections break internally - have been repaired by some.

Oh, have lots of plasters to hand and make sure you are in an area where the kids can't hear you : the access (used loosely...) is VERY restricted... :)

If I find a picture...sourced from jag pdf manual and the red oval is the location - notice the lack of chassis, radiator etc etc... :)

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is a Duratorq engine, thanks alot for your description! I will have a look at it when I'm back from work. The picture really helps me, I can already see what you mean... this is going to be "fun". At least I know the general area as I'm already aquainted with the dreadful EGR valve.

Comment: my egr has a blank fitted with the 8mm hole... seems to be happier...

Answer (score -1):

unfortunately the picture does not fit. I have a BA 7 / MK4 built in 2009 with the 2.2 l / 175 PS TDCI. The engine compartment looks a little different. It should e.g. for cable harness problems (including in connection with air conditioning [but I have no obvious problems]) issue TSI 25/2011. Perhaps a possible cable problem could be localized somewhat in the strand? ... Unfortunately there are no longer "freely" available exploded drawings of the cars. With the current status, it is still not worth contacting me by phone, because I can not always operate with the phone and under the hood ...